# segue to the TabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my image, my first Tabbar is HomeViewController and the second Tabbar is CameraViewController.
What is the proper way to segue to the Tabbarcontroller? You can see the read line, I try to segue this but I 
always get the back button in my HomeViewController and It display weird like not showing the navigation name. 
In CameraViewController I hide the Tabbar for the use camera button. I try to use segue programmatically like this one.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sample" sender:sender]
```

but It doesn't work properly. Is this possible to segue to TabbarController?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sample" sender:sender]
```

Because you're in TabBarController already. You could implement custom flow. By pressing "Back" button - just show TabBar and change selected tabBarItem for example…

**update**
used this

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Comment: do I need to code this? honestly I don't know how to do it. I'm confuse. sorry

Comment: Add into your IBAction method for back button this call "[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; // or any another index :)"

Comment: it doesn't show tabbar menu at the button, but It display very well the navigation without back button.

Comment: How are you hiding tabBar? Try to set checkmark "Hide Bottom Bar on Push" in you storyboard for CameraViewController

Comment: I get it now. In my CameraViewController. I set it to hide the tabbar. thanks for this. Can you update your answer so that I can check this. thank you very much